# Apache 'always set' headers removed if mod_expires ExpiresActive On

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers

I have a following directives in my virtual host:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=157700000;"
Header always set ThisIsATestHeader "This is removed when ever ExpiresActive is on"
Header merge AnotherHeader "This will NOT be removed"
```

Then I turn on mod_expires with:

```
ExpiresActive on
```

As a result all headers set with `always set` are gone! The merged header however will stay.
Why is that? If that is intentional, how should I deal with this in regards of the HSTS header, which in my understanding must be present at all times?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem and half of the answer.

Aparently the conditional `always` is not behaving as excpected. In particular case the actual behaviour seems to be more like `notsuccess`. The headers set with `always` conditional are present for example on redirect responses, but not on succes. This makes sense, since the `ExpiresActive` directive will not be executed on redirect.

Why is that happening when `mod_expires` is turned on, is still a mystery. There is a [comment on apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#comment_349) about this happening also with reverse proxy.

To overcome this I came up with the **solution** to add the header twice, one for non 2** response and one for 2** response. So in my case it would be:

```
# For redirects    
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=157700000;"
# For success
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=157700000;"
```

Now it is set for any request as the conditional `always` failed to do with mod_expires turned on.